# Имитация нажатия на ссылку или что то вроде.+)

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте. 
Есть вот такая ссылка.

```
<a href="#myModalL" role="button" class="login-top" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> &nbsp; <?php _e("Sign in", 'reach'); ?></a>
```

По нажатию открывается модальное окно с `id="myModalL".`

Нужно сделать так, чтобы переходе на страницу это окно открывалось по php условию. 
Вот и вопрос. Как открыть его по этому условию=)

И вот Js который собственно его и открывает.

```
$('.button').click(function() {

        type = $(this).attr('data-type');

        $('.overlay-container').fadeIn(function() {

            window.setTimeout(function(){
                $('.window-container.'+type).addClass('window-container-visible');
            }, 100);

        });
    });

    $('.close').click(function() {
        $('.overlay-container').fadeOut().end().find('.window-container').removeClass('window-container-visible');
    });

});
```

Comment: @RattleSneyk

    if ($condition) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">$('.button').click();</script>
    <?php }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$('#myModalL').modal('show')](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage)

> The modal plugin toggles your hidden content on demand, via data attributes or JavaScript. It also adds .modal-open to the `<body>` to override default scrolling behavior and generates a `.modal-backdrop` to provide a click area for dismissing shown modals when clicking outside the modal.